# How to make list to be printed line by line from csv using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, email, outlook

I am using this code

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client as win32


mailer=''

data1=pd.read_csv('E:\\Report(3).csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
a=data1['Assignee+'].count()
mailer=mailer+"Total Number of tickets resolved"+str(a)
#print(a)

print("Total Number Of Tickets Resolved This Week = " + str(data1['Assignee+'].count()) + "")
s = data1['Assignee+'].value_counts()
```

And i am getting output as

```
Total Number of tickets resolved517Jeyalakshmi Sivaselvaraj        56
Madan Chenchuraju               52
Naresh Elango                   49
Hemachandran Mohan              49
```

But when i add these  code into my code,

```
Application = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

Msg = Application.CreateItem(0)

Msg.To = 'madanraj.c@prodapt.com'
Msg.HTMLBody = '<b>'+ mailer +'</b>'
Msg.Send()
```

I am getting mail as

```
Total Number of tickets resolved517 Jeyalakshmi Sivaselvaraj 56 Madan Chenchuraju 52 Naresh Elango 49 Hemachandran Mohan 49
```

How to get mail line by line?

Comment: what variabble stores `Total Number of tickets resolved517 Jeyalakshmi Sivaselvaraj 56 Madan Chenchuraju .......................`

Comment: s variable stores and also mailer stores, i didn include.

Comment: The variable 's' stores, and mailer=mailer+str(s).. I didn include this line. That doesnt matter though.. I  need as seperate lines..

Comment: Try `mailer=mailer + str(s) +'\n'`

Comment: It just included new line at the end, I want for each name and number togethr which is store in s as a list.

Comment: S and mailer both are same , i just using mailer for my convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mailer or s is just plain string and that you want to embed in your html mail body part. Since html has it own syntax with tags to compose mail, I would suggest you to visit [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/) for more detailed references.

For example in your case, check out the below code. It will generate html table tags suitable for your email, more details you can find in w3school link:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Asignee':['Jeyalakshmi', 'Madan', 'Naresh', 'Hemachandran'], 'Count': [56, 52, 49, 49]})
buf = df.to_html()
print(buf)
```

And this generates the buf as shown below:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Asignee</th>
      <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Jeyalakshmi</td>
      <td>56</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Madan</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>Naresh</td>
      <td>49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td>Hemachandran</td>
      <td>49</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the same in you html email it will look similar to below table:

```
        Asignee  Count
0   Jeyalakshmi     56
1         Madan     52
2        Naresh     49
3  Hemachandran     49
```

Comment: This will be helpful only if i give the data, I am using value count and it doesnt fit for it. Please help this for better.

Comment: As it is not clear what is your input dataframe and what operations you perform on that dataframe to update / modify / add it, so I cannot give you the exact solution. I have given you helpful info using which you can solve your problem at hand.